# Firestore on a 4g or other mobile connection?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I build an Flutter app using the cloud Firestore 0.8.0 plugin with persistence enabled. 
When I'm connected to wifi, data updates in Realtime.
But when I'm connected to 4g/mobile data, it is not updating at all.
Is this intended, or do I have to change something?

This is my pubspec

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  #firebase
  firebase_core: "0.2.5+1"
  firebase_analytics: "1.0.6"
  cloud_firestore: "0.8.0"
  firebase_remote_config: "0.0.6+1"
  #firebase
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"
  rxdart: "^0.18.1"
  url_launcher: "^3.0.3"
  cached_network_image: "0.5.0"
  http: "^0.12.0"
  intl: "^0.15.6"
  fluro: "^1.3.4"
  flutter_list_drag_and_drop: "^0.1.6"
  flutter_statusbarcolor: "0.1.3"
  device_info: "^0.3.0"
  share: "^0.5.3"
  palette_generator: "^0.1.1"
  connectivity: "^0.3.2"
  flutter_advanced_networkimage: "^0.3.11"
  device_calendar: "^0.0.7"
  flutter_local_notifications: "^0.4.2"
```

If you are wondering why I don't use the latest version of firestore, it is because I got this error

```
flutter app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug
```

And only downgrading worked

Comment: Have you configured [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline)?

Comment: Yes I have. It is set to true.

Comment: So if you disable then connection at all (e.g. fly-mode), you see the already downloaded data. Ain't it?

Comment: Yes once downloaded data is available when I'm offline. But it doesn't update when I'm on mobile data only on a WiFi connection.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Actually I didn't use it but I've used realtime db in the past. What I've found out is that on poor connection firebase didn't get the data from persistence but try to download the live data without updating views. But in my case, even if it took long to show the data, after a while the views were populated accordingly. So I leave you with this test: try to simulate a slow WiFi connection and see if it behaves the same. Do that while waiting for someone that maybe actually knows the exact reason why. ^_^

Comment: Will test it tomorrow and report back, thanks!

Comment: @shadowsheep I tried:
A good LTE connection, it worked ok,
A bad LTE connection, hugh delay,
A good EDGE connection, hugh delay,
A bad EDGE connection, no update,
A good wifi connection, instant update,
A bad wifi connection, delay,
But as you said on a bad (and mobile) connection the ui somethimes did not update.

Comment: So it’s like we have thought. It behaves the same as realtime db. At the very end I resign using realtime db but if I would have decided to use it I would have check for connectivity and tryied to find a way to force firebase to use the persisted data until live data would have been available. But actually I don’t know how to do. Btw if you find a way please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185717/discussion-between-johann-feser-and-shadowsheep).